# Devising optimzed algorithms for restricted-range partition problem

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, complexity-theory, subset-sum

First of all, I'm referring to the 'partition problem' as the decision problem on whether some multiset of positive integers `S` can be partitioned into two equal-valued subsets. It is known that although this problem is NP-Complete, it can be solved in pseudo-linear O(nm) time via dynamic programming, where `n` is the number of integers in `S`, and `m` is half the sum of those integers (i.e. the target sum for each multiset). Here is an example of this approach in JS: https://pastebin.com/GETrGwqh.

However, since m tends to scale up linearly with n (more precisely, linearly with the mean value of S), this O(nm) approach can still be quite inefficient for large n. Yet it seems to me that more efficient algorithms could be devised for range-restricted instances of the partition problem, where the value of the largest possible integer in `S`, `k`, is known in advance, and `k` is small. To discuss some examples, let's represent `S` as `[n_1, n_2,...n_k]`, where each `n_i` represents the number of `i`'s in S (e.g. [3, 0, 1, 2] represents the mset {1,1,1,3,4,4}). Below, we see that the k=1 and k=2 cases are very simple:

```
partition = [n_1] => n_1 % 2 == 0
```

(any even number of 1's can be partitioned evenly, and any odd number cannot)

```
partition = [n_1,n_2] => {
  if (n_1 % 2) return false
  return n_2 % 2 || n_1 >= 2 // (didn't exit, so n_1 is even)
}
```

(if n_1 is odd, the sum is odd, so return false. If both n_1 and n_2 are even, there is a trivial partition, but if instead n_2 is odd and n_1 >= 2, you can use a pair of 1's to offset the odd 2. Otherwise, there is no possible partition)

When we extend to the k=3 case, using a similar, parity-based approach, there are 2^3=8 possible cases, 4 of which are trivially false because they yield odd sums (the cases were n_1 and n_3 do not share the same parity), and one of which (the all even [e,e,e]) is trivially true (just take half of each n_i to partition). However, I'm struggling to derive rules for the [e,o,e], [o,e,o], and [o,o,o] instances which are potentially partition-able because they yield even sums, but not necessarily so.

So to sum up my question, I'm wondering if there are some additional conditional checks that could be applied to solve the k=3 case in constant (or perhaps O(2^k)) time, and whether similar 'constant time' algorithms could be derived for k=4,5,6... because even if the logical complexity/number of conditions to check grows exponentially in k, algorithms derived specifically for range-restricted partition instances could still be preferable to the generally applicable O(nm) DP solutions for n and m very large relative to k.

Putting this in a more directly mathematical light, the above process would be equivalent in complexity to determining the existence of satisfying m_1,...m_k in the following constrained Diophantine equation, where the lefthand side represents half the sum of all the integers in the set, and the m_i coeffecients on the right hand side (to be solved for) represent the partition in terms of the quantities of each integer:

[image: diophantine equation]

(Which I don't know how I'd go about solving, but thought I'd throw it out there in case it sparks someone's imagination).

Comment: There should be an O(n) time algorithm for each fixed k, based on first counting the element frequencies to produce an array of length k (zeroes don't matter and can be ignored), and then solving the problem using some logic on that array, whose size is independent of n.

Comment: That was my intuition too, but I'm wondering how to generate these specialized algorithms for k-restricted instances, if there is a pattern to exploit in writing them/what kind of logic we need to perform on the k-array once it's determined, and whether/how the complexity of that logic scales with k